# What is a chain of words like this called?

Tags: word-request

Take this for instance:

> Organelles --> Cell --> Tissue --> Organ --> Organ system --> Organism

How about "order of development"? I'm really clueless actually, but I'm pretty certain there is a specific term for it, though I may not be able to recall it now.

Answer (score 2):

In biology this is an extensive topic that cannot be entirely summed up in a single word or phrase, but (at a basic level) is taught as the [**Levels of Organization**](https://sciencing.com/levels-organization-biology-8480388.html) related to [**Biological Complexity**](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/biological-complexity-and-integrative-levels-of-organization-468).

In practice the complexity goes well below the level of organelles, down to proteins and molecules, and well above organisms into groups, species, communities, ecosystems, and eventually the entire biosphere of the planet.

Comment: I think level of organization is right. The complexity thing is another issue.

Comment: @Lambie  Complexity is the underlying concept that more or less defines where each level begins and ends.  But as with most subjects young students are taught some basics -- it's easier to memorize a set list than to comprehend the theory.

Comment: increasing level of biological complexity.

Comment: @Andrew I was looking for something more general.

Comment: @Soha Farhin Pine "increasing level of biological complexity" is general.